# Why I can't choose the number for contact with multiple numbers when I send a SMS?

Tags: contacts, sms

When I send a SMS to a contact who has two numbers,Windows Phone doesn't give an option to choose which number should receive the SMS. Why Windows Phone doesn't ask me to choose which number I want to send the SMS and sends automatically to the first number to given contact? Is there an option to control this feature hidden somewhere?

My phone: Microsoft Lumia 640 XL with Window 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you send a SMS. There are 2 ways to create a new message. Method 2 will provide the solution to your problem.

**Method 1** :

1. Open the Contact profile either from People app or Call history
2. If you have 2 numbers stored in the same profile/contact you will see only one *text* button below.

[image: Sample contact profile - WP]

Clicking on this will send the Message to the first number in the mobile category.

Note : Text option is not shown for number stored in Home category even if it is the only number present.

[image: Contact profile - No text option]

**Method 2 :** This method is a solution to your problem too.

1. Open Messaging app.
2. Click on the plus sign located at the bottom.

[image: New message]

3. Now type the contact name at the top. As Rowland Shaw [said](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12716/18061) it will Auto suggest contacts numbers. As you can see in the picture, both numbers of the contacts are shown.

[image: Auto suggest in message]

Now you can select a number to send message to.

Answer (score 4):

Normally when typing a contact's name, you'll get an auto complete list of all the matches, with all the numbers for those matches -  you can then choose to send to (say) their work number or their mobile number, etc.